# Enable/Disable Links in MVC Project

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I know there has been a lot of posts about this topic but none that explains what I want to do. I am working on a large MVC Project with more than a hundred Models, views and controllers.

The main menu items are stored in the database with there urls and the rest of the links are just hardcoded href.

When the project is run and you log in it shows a dashboard with a drop down on the left from witch you must select a complex with witch you are going to work. By default there is no complex selected. I want to disable all the links except the one where you go to add a new complex and when you select a complex it must enable them again. Can any one point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to find the `anchor` (link) and disable it.

Disabling all:

```
$(this).find('a').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

You can iterate through them all by using an [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) statement.

```
$.each('a', function()
{
  if ($(this).attr('href') !== '/Complex/Add' && $(this).attr('href') !== '/Complex/Index') // your filter
  {
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

You can also prevent clicking with this:

```
$('a').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Server side you can use this when using ActionLink for example:

```
if (!checkLinkEnabled)
{
    helper.ActionLink( "link text"
                     , actionName
                     , controller
                     , routeValues
                     , htmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object>
                       { { "disabled", "disabled" }
                       }
                     );
}
```

Comment: I have partial views rendering Inside each other so I can not just apply this script in one of my views, because it doesn't affect the other partially rendered views. At this stage `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(this).find('a').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>` is not working at all on any view. Isn't there a way to do this server side or another approach

Comment: What I normally do is wrapping this behavior in an extension method. It checks inside if the option is available and write html elements accordingly. See my update in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If your open to jQuery You can try

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    if(this.id !== 'YourDefaultElementID' && CheckForYourCondition == false){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Here I have binded event with all anchor tag. Either use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;` to prevent default action

### EDIT

As per comment

*I want to disable all of the 'a' elements except the the one with the 'href=': `#/Complex/Add` & `#/Complex/Index`.*

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    if($(this).attr('href') !== '#/Complex/Add' 
        && $(this).attr('href') !== '#/Complex/Index'
        && CheckForYourCondition == false){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Using JQuery would be best as its the standard. Okay I understand what you are doing. Lets say I want to disable all of the `'a'` elements except the the one with the `'href='`: `#/Complex/Add` & `#/Complex/Index`. How would you sugest?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about MVC much . .But Links can be hidden by using CSS ; 
You can achieve this by either using JavaScript or by Using Code-Back [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter.AddStyleAttribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the client from reaching a particular page **don't** use JavaScript (or any other client side way of doing it). By disabling something client side, by definition it means it can be re-enabled client side also. Also no amount of JavaScript or css can stop someone manually just typing in the url of a page in the address bar at any point.

If a user should not be able to visit the '/Complex/Edit' page until they have an active complex then this should be handled server side. Firstly when building your view your model should dictate that there is no active complex yet and so don't render any links that require an active complex.

Secondly to handle the fact that a user can always just manually type in a pages url you will need to do some checks in your controller action to see if they have already selected a complex. If not then redirect them to an appropriate page informing them so.

Comment: This is not for security reasons it is just to set a fixed path that must be followed to set up the application as there has already been privileges applied to the accounts.

Comment: Regardless of security its just good practice to only return the html the view needs rather than returning a incorrect html response which you then 'clean up' with javascript.